# How can we expand (logn)! and (logn!)! to determine the complexities?

Tags: algorithm

I know that log n! gives a complexity of O(nlogn) but how to exapnd the above? The second one may be simplified to (nlogn)!. Please clarify on this.

Comment: You can use Gamma function to replace n!

Comment: Does `(logn)! = (log(n))!`? and `(logn!)! = (log(n!))!`?

Answer (score 3):

You could estimate upper and lower bounds for `(log(n))!` using the identity
[image: x^log(y)=y^log(x)] together with product estimations.

For an upper bound:

> [image: upper bound]

For a lower bound:

> [image: lowerbound]

Combined you will get:

> [image: combined]

So at least:

> [image: O(n^{log(log(n))})]

Obviously, the (in)equations are somehow 'odd' due to the non-integer index boundaries of the products.

**Update:**
The bound given by [hwlau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535615/hwlau) using the sterling approximation is lower (by `sqrt(log(n))/n`) and should be tight.

> [image: tighter bounds]

Comment: Just a reminder, your case is a loose upper bound compared with mine. $$N^(ln(ln N))  =  O( lnN^(lnN+1/2)/n )$$

Comment: Yeah that's true. PS: It must be Ω instead of O in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: No, you cannot use `(N ln N)!` in your second formula. The reason is explained below using the first case.

With the [log version of Stirling approximation](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/40asymptotic/), we have

```
ln(z!) = (z+1/2) ln z - z + O(1)...
```

Note that the extra `z` is kept here, the reason will be obvious soon. Now if we let `x = log N`,

```
(ln N)! = x! = exp(ln x!)
~ exp((x+1/2) ln x - x) = x^(x+1/2) exp(-x)
= (ln N)^((ln N)+1/2) / N
```

The extra term we kept turns out to be a inverse of `N`, it definitely has effects on the complexity since we cannot simply throw away of exp of something. If we denote `g(N)` for the approximation above and `f(N) = (ln N)!`, then `lim f(N)/g(N) = sqrt(2 pi) < inf`, so `f = O(g)`

For the `(ln N!)!`, it is a bit complicated, I use mathematica to check for the limit, and it suggests that the expansion

```
ln(z!) ~ (z+1/2) ln z - z + ln(sqrt(2pi))
```

is enough. I don't have general rule for when we can stop. And in general, it may not be possible to use only finite terms. But in this case, we can.

In case you only need a loose bound, for the first formula, you can actually throw away of the `-z` term because `(z+1/2) ln z  >  (z+1/2) ln z - z`.

Comment: user2697032 was talking about `(logn!)!` not `log(n!)`